# DateTime::createFromFormat return wrong date

Tags: php

I call: `DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '32/12/2016');`
Result: 2018-08-12 23:28:30

I don't know why it return that result. Any help. Thanks

Comment: What kind of date is 32/12/2016?

Comment: It's an invalid date. I want to check if it's a valid date. Thanks for your answer below. I miss understood this function.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on date functions alone to validate a date.

Comment: Thanks @Devon: I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified 32 months.  32 months is 2 years + 8 months, so it's using the 8th month and advancing the years by 2.